# How to generate numbers so that there's never a back-to-back array index value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, event-handling

I need some help in revising the JavaScript to ensure that each click generates a current colors index value different from the previous index value i.e. to ensures that the index numbers are never consecutively repeated as the button is clicked.

```js
var colors = ["green", "red", "rgba(133,122,200)", "yellow"];
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const color = document.querySelector('.color');
btn.addEventListener('click',  randomColor);

function randomColor() {
  var previous = 0;
  var value;
  var max = 4 + (!isNaN(previous) ? -1 : 0);
  value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max));
  if (value >= previous) {
    value += 1; 
  }
  previous = value;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[value];
  color.innerText = colors[value];
  return value;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>background color: 
      <span class="color">#f1f5f</span>
    </h2>
    <button class="btn btn-hero" id="btn">click me</button>  
  </div>   
</main>
```

Comment: read the current color, set next color with random, while next color equals current color: set next color with random.  after loop: use next color value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var colors = ["green", "red", "rgba(133,122,200)", "yellow"];
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const color = document.querySelector('.color');
btn.addEventListener('click',  randomColor);

function randomColor() {
  if(colors.length>1) {
    var next;
    do {
      next=colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    } while (next==color.innerText);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = next;
    color.innerText = next;
  }
  else {
    console.log("Not enough colors");
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>background color: 
      <span class="color">white</span>
    </h2>
    <button class="btn btn-hero" id="btn">click me</button>  
  </div>   
</main>
```

Comment: Hey dude, thanks for helping me out. It works as expected. But I am unclear about how exactly that do/while statement prevents the same color from ever repeating back-to-back.

Comment: `while` checks a condition, much like `if`, and if the condition evaluates to `true` - it loops and repeats from `while`, if it evaluates to `false` - it falls out of the loop and continues next line of code.

Comment: `var next` declares next with value `undefined`.
`do` assigns a random color to `next`.
`while` compares `next`'s value to `color.innerText`.
As long as the random color is the same as the color in the span, it will keep trying another random color.
That's why I've added a check to see that there are at least 2 colors to chose from - one or none will cause an infinite loop - one will change color once, because `white` is not in the `colors` array.

Comment: As soon as I posted that comment, it just hit me. I figured it out! Thanks a mill for taking the time. Learning slowly but surely.